# Disable -Wreturn-type checking

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am trying to compile [Model 5.0](http://people.unica.it/massimilianoarca/lang/it/2012/02/25/how-to-compile-molden-5-0-under-mac-os-x-lion/?repeat=w3tc) under OS X 10.8.3
I am getting a lot of warnings and errors while compiling. Several of those error are something like

```
xwin.c:31523:2: error: non-void function 'scrfrg' should return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
        return;
```

What flag in C/C++ checks that? I want to disable it and try to finish the compilation.
I'm not sure if this is the best forum to ask this, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: A non-void function must return a value, otherwise the behaviour is undefined. Recommend not disabling and ignoring that error.

Comment: gcc 4.2.1 but I have to say it uses also gfortran (4.6.2) for linking I think

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the link you posted, seems you're using gcc. You can disable a lot of error/warning checks with a `-Wno-xxxx` flag, in your case `-Wreturn-type` is causing an error so you can disable it with:

`-Wno-return-type`

Frankly, it's better to just fix the errors/warnings when you can, and that one seems easy to fix.

Comment: Yeah sure, I know it would be better but I'm not the developer of the app and honestly I don't want to invest time checking the code. I contacted the guy that develops it hope he can help with those errors.

Comment: @BRabbit27 - `"I don't want to invest time checking the code"` That's understandable, but keep in mind that errors/warnings are in there for a reason, you might get this code to *compile* by ignoring all the errors but you'll find it doesn't work at all and that could have been rectified by fixing the problems. Best of luck to you.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments I just want to have it compiled as I have work to do with that app. Also I contacted the guy who is in charge of developing the application and I hope he corrects the code.